# Creating an interactive graph for a science experiment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been asked whether it is possible to create an online simulator for quite a complex science experiment and need some advice to figure out how to do it.

The functionality I need is:

1) have input fields (variables) that are all changeable by the user and influence the result

2) A line graph that shows the result of the experiment - This needs to plot over set periods of time to replicate a realistic experiment

I was wondering if this kind of thing could be recreated so it can be viewed in-browser using jQuery?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Learn HTML, jQuery then proceed with Fusion Charts or another chart plugins.

Comment: It is definitely doable

Comment: Would I need to use Fusion Charts? It's quite expensive. I have a reasonably good understanding of HTML and CSS, but still learning jQuery

Comment: Better start learning pure Javascript (you can also combine it with jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Learn some basics, html/js;
2. Take a js framework, I suggest angular: [**LINK**](http://angularjs.org)
   but you choose any you want.
3. Here, I agree with @Echo, Fusion Charts is ok. You can also take a look at another js library for charts/graphics - http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

there are many jquery based graph frameworks.
For me [highcharts.com](http://highcharts.com) is the best and free (for open source projects).

Comment: Ok thanks, that's a couple of people who have mentioned High Charts to me